# Probability problem(sample size)

Tags: probability

If attacked by a zombie, green poison would float in the blood of the victim. We try to find the average concentration of poison found in the blood of victims. In our research, we found that the poison concentration is normally distributed with a variance of 0.20.
What sample size is needed so that the width of a 90% confidence interval for μ will be 0.15?

Here, the given variance is 0.2, alpha = 0.1, width = 0.15,
n is sample size, width = 2*Zα*variance/sqrt(n) and this equals 0.15, Z0.1 = 1.645, so I get n = ((2*1.645*0.2)/0.15 )^2 = 19, so thesample size is 19, but it seems incorrect, can anyone tell me which part went wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The minimum sample size is

$$n\geq\left(  \frac{2\sigma\cdot z_{\alpha/2}}{d} \right)^2=\left(  \frac{2\sqrt{0.2}\cdot 1.645}{0.15} \right)^2=96.2\approx 97$$

This known formula is very easy to be proved. In fact, consider that the CI for $\mu$ is

$$\overline{X}-\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}\cdot z\leq \mu\leq \overline{X}+\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}\cdot z$$

that is

$$a\leq \mu\leq b$$

thus the interval's widht is

$$d=b-a$$

$$d=\frac{2\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}\cdot z$$

...easy solve this equation in $n$ finding the requested formula

Comment: Looks like I got the formula wrong, thanks!

Comment: @jason: added some details to prove the formula you need ;)